# Loading values in a DDL using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to display values in a DDL using a XML file and i am using LINQ to XML

```
  <countrys>
  <country>
    <name>India</name>
    <state>
      <text>Maharashtra</text>
      <text>Kashmir</text>
      <text>Goa</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>Sri lanka</name>
    <state>
      <text>Kanady</text>
      <text>Colombo</text>
      <text>Galle</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name> Australia</name>
    <state>
      <text>Sydney</text>
      <text>Perth</text>
      <text>Melbourne</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>South Africa</name>
    <state>
      <text>Capetown</text>
      <text>Johanusburg</text>
      <text>Durban</text>
    </state>
  </country>
</countrys>

     public static IEnumerable bindstate()
        {
            var state = from b in getdata().Descendants(("state"))
                        orderby (string) b.Element("text")
                        select (string) b.Element("text");
            return state;

        }
```

but i am not getting all the states i am getting only first state in every country how can i get all the states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) for this:

```
var state = from b in getdata().Descendants("state")
                               .SelectMany(state => state.Elements("text"))
            orderby (string) b
            select (string) b;
```

In this example, `SelectMany` selects the `"text"` elements from each `"state"` element and flattens them into one sequence.

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to writing `var state = from s in getdata().Descendants("state") from b in s.Elements("text") orderby (string)b select (string)b;`